# Ruby Array Comparison Without Deleting Duplicates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, include

I have seen many questions regarding this, but not one that addresses the issue of duplicate values.

Below are two arrays. I need to verify `ary2` is included in `ary1` regardless of the extra duplicates. Also needs to work regardless if the arrays are holding numbers or characters.

```
ary1 = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
ary2 = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5]
```

Should equal `[1, 1, 2, 3, 5]`, my code equals `[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 5]`

Tried many options, including `keep_if` or `keep_at`, `delete_if` or `delete_at`, `slice`, `map`, etc.

Current code:

```
ary1.keep_if { |x| ary2.include?(x) }
```

Comment: You say you wish to verify that `ary2` is included in `ary1`. That requires a `true` or `false` answer, but you then say the answer should be `[1,1,2,3,5]`. That makes no sense. Suppose `ary1 = [1]` and `ary2 = [1,1]`. In his case is `ary2` "included" in `ary1`? Please edit your question to clarify what you are asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> to verify ary2 is included in ary1

```
(ary2 - ary1).empty?
```

> should equal `[1, 1, 2, 3, 5]`

```
ary2.select { |e| ary1.include?(e) }
```

Comment: Works great. What if I want to find what is left in ary1 after select has been used. I have tried reject, but it deletes the duplicates as well.

Comment: ary1.select { |e| !ary2.include?(e) }

Answer (score 0):

Reading between the lines, I'm assuming that "`ary2` is *included* in `ary1`" means that, for each element of `ary2`, there a unique element of `ary1` with the same value. By "unique" I mean, for example, that if `ary2` contains two `1`'s, `ary1` must contains two or more `1`'s. If this interpretation of the question is incorrect there is no reason to read further.

If my assumption is correct, we could construct a method (with arguments `ary1` and `ary2`) that returns `true` or `false`, but if there is a match (`true`) it might be more useful to return the elements of `ary1` that are "left over" after elements of `ary1` have been matched to the elements of `ayr2`.

```
def ary2_included_in_ary1?(ary1, ary2)
  ary1_cpy = ary1.dup
  ary2.all? do |n|
    idx = ary1_cpy.index n
    return false if idx.nil?
    ary1_cpy.delete_at(idx)
  end
  ary1_cpy
end

ary1 = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

ary2 = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5]
ary2_included_in_ary1?(ary1, ary2)
  #=> [1, 2, 4, 6]

ary2 = [1, 1, 2, 3, 7]
ary2_included_in_ary1?(ary1, ary2)
#=> false
```